# How to programmatically set the date and time of the Publish field of Publishing section in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

```
XmlNode jobPostDate = xmlDocumentObject.SelectSingleNode("MsgData/HRS_JO_PST_OPN_DT)
var jPdate = jobPostDate.InnerText;
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(jPdate);
var HRS_JO_PST_OPN_DT = dt1;
newItem.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.PublishDate].Value = HRS_JO_PST_OPN_DT.ToString();
```

I am using the above code to get the date (01/09/2013) and set it to the Publish field, but I am getting '1/1/0001' values, shown in below picture, in the field.

[image: Publishing section with Publish and Unpublish set to '1/1/0001']

Please advise what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this to set the value of the date field:

```
newItem.Publishing.PublishDate = dt1;
```

Use the `Publishing.UnPublishDate` property to set the unpublish date

Comment: Please select this answer as the solution. Gives me some points ;)

Comment: @Sam, if this answer works for you, please accept it. Besides improving Martin's karma, this fact will give a great hint to others visiting  this thread. That's the way stackoverflow.com works - respect it.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko i am new to stackoverflow.com and step by step learning the working of the site.